# Losing order of sorted queryset With Django-Endless-Pagination

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

I've got a few sorted querysets im passing to a template. Multiple paginations are shown per page. The problem is after the first series of paginated items, subsequent ones lose their sort. Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
    def entry_index(request, parent_cat, child_cat, template='entry_index.html',  
                    page_template='entry_index_page.html'):  
                context = { 'items_by_percentage_saved':  
                     Item.objects.filter(category=category).order_by('-percentage_saved'),  }
                if request.is_ajax():
                    template = page_template
                    return render_to_response(template, context,  
                                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**by_percentage_saved.html**

```
{% load endless %}
{% paginate items_by_percentage_saved %}
{% for item in items_by_percentage_saved %}
<div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
  <a class="th" href=""><img style="height: 12em;" src={{ item.image_url }}></a>

  <div class="panel">
    <h5>{{ item.title|truncatechars:50 }}</h5>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% show_more %}
```

**Update**
I've done some more debugging and the `items_by_percentage_saved` queryset is definitely sorted in `entry_index()`. I put a few breakpoints in `by_percentage_saved.html` to see if I could figure out whats going on, but strangely after you click "more" to get the next paginated data, `entry_index()` is called again but the breakpoints never fire a second time in `by_percentage_saved.html`, even though the new paginated data is generated. Talk about confusing

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo, but you are cycling over `page_items` instead of ìtems_by_percentage_saved`. Can it be the problem?

Comment: What does `{% paginate items_by_percentage_saved %}` do exactly?

Comment: @Germano, good spot, yeah it's a typo from where I was trying a few different things to get it working. Haved fixed the typo.

Comment: @EWit i'm haven't fully got my head around the package, but according to the docs http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html "After this call, the (following) variable in the template context is replaced by only the entries of the current page."

I'm guessing like me you think `{% paginate items_by_percentage_saved %}` is where the problem lies?

Comment: @KingFu No that function looks pretty clean actually. Do you have the rendering code of the other series of pagination? or is that a loop over the top piece replacing items_by_percentage_saved with something different all the time?

Comment: @EWit, each template (by_lowest_cost.html, by_highest_cost.html) is exactly the same as the one I've included and all included in a parent template. There's no extra logic running. I assume `{% paginate items_by_percentage_saved %}` is like you say is doing some paginating magic to the `items_by_percentage_saved` for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok have solved it by going through the docs again and using page decorators. The docs kinda make it sound like these are optional but my guess they are a requirement for multiple pagination on the same page.

`from endless_pagination.decorators import page_template
@page_template('entry_index_page.html')

@page_template('by_percentage_saved.html', key='by_percentage_saved')

def entry_index(request, parent_cat, child_cat, template='entry_index.html',

                        extra_context=None):`